# How to get reports in windows c# webapplication using Trimble Maps Report API

Tags: trimble-maps

I am craeting a trip in webapplication using c#. Everything working as expected no error. But when I am trying to get reports using any reporting method like PCMSGetRptLine,or PCMSGetRpt.It stops working and no error reported. but hang everything.

Anyone have an idea how to use these report API in c# webapplication with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using .Net C# to call non .Net Connect C++ APIs.

Sample C# (sharp) source code is in the …\ALK Technologies\PCMILERXX\Connect\CSharp folder, wherever you installed PC*MILER. (XX is your PC*MILER version number.)

PC*MILER also has RESTful web APIs that can be used to generate the same reports and may be easier to integrate using C#.